# R: Convert binary file to matrix

Tags: matrix, binary, binaryfiles

R: I uploaded a big binary file (numeric, one array) into R with readBin.
My data is composed of values bigger than 10000 and values smaller than 10000, like

```
25685, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 46789, 6, 2, 9, 44220, 5, 1, 3, 7, 9, 12, 88952, 6, 8,...
```

How can I separate the values, so that I can create a matrix?

```
1: 25685, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5

2: 46789, 6, 2, 9

3: 44220, 5, 1, 3, 7, 9, 12
```

The separation should be between the last small value and the big value like above.

Comment: sep<-which(rB>12000) # time steps
len<-diff(sep,1) # lags
len<-c(len,(length(rB)-tail(sep,1))) # last value
mat<-matrix(NA, size/8,3) # matrix
for(i in 1:length(sep)) # fill the matrix
  {mat[sep[i]:(sep[i]+len[i]),1]<-i
   mat[sep[i]:(sep[i]+len[i]-1),2]<-(1:len[i])
   mat[sep[i]:(sep[i]+len[i]-1),3]<-rB[sep[i]:(sep[i]+len[i]-1)]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name<-file(".dat", "rb")
size<-(file.info("Path/Name.dat")$size)/8
rB<-readBin(name, numeric(), size, endian="little")
size<-length(rB)
sep<-which(rB>10000) # time steps
len<-diff(sep,1) # lags
len<-c(len,(length(rB)-tail(sep,1)+1)) # last value
mat<-matrix(NA,(size-length(sep)+14),4) # matrix
for(i in 1:(length(sep))) # fill the matrix
{
mat[sep[i]:(sep[i]+len[i]-2),1]<-i
mat[(sep[i]):(sep[i]+len[i]-2),2]<-(1:(len[i]-1))
mat[(sep[i]):(sep[i]+len[i]-2),3]<-rB[sep[i]]    
mat[(sep[i]):(sep[i]+len[i]-2),4]<-rB[(sep[i]+1):(sep[i]+len[i]-1)]
}
mat<-mat[which(!is.na(mat[,1])),]
```